# Anybody recognize this flat-flex connector?

Tags: connector, identification

Even after a few hours Googling, I'm unable to identify this flat-flex connector, so I'm thinking it's time to turn to the community for help!

The connector in question is this guy:

[image: Flat-flex connector without callouts]

Of course, I already looked for identifying info such as brand, etc., but was only rewarded with a few generic/informational markings:

- "43 2B" in the upper-left-hand corner (on the back retention clip of the connector)
- "1A" in the bottom-right-hand corner

Other things I know about the connector:

- it has 43 circuits
- 14.25mm length
- 3.75mm width (with retention clip closed)
- flex cable contacts are all the same size, but staggered into two rows
- either 0.5 or 0.3mm pitch (hard to tell, given the staggering)

Here's the same shot of the connector with magnification in each corner (I've verified these markings by viewing/lighting at other angles; not included).

[image: Connector with callouts]

Any help that anyone can offer here would be massively appreciated!

Comment: [DigiKey has a category for FFC connectors.](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/1442849)  If you filter for *number of positions* equal 43, the filter returns only 24 results.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yeah, I know -- I looked there and didn't think I saw it, but I'll certainly check again! Thanks for your input, either way :)

Comment: @NickAlexeev It looks like I checked Mouser but not DigiKey! For anyone wondering, it looks like the Molex Easy-On™ 503555 series may include this part!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a comment from Nick Alexeev (above, in comments), I realized that I had managed to check Mouser, Jameco, etc. but neglected to check DigiKey (of all places).

It appears that this part is one of the Molex Easy-On™ 503555 series connectors; specifically the [5035664300](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/5035664300/WM8969CT-ND/3197398). Taking a look at the datasheet, the flex side of the connector also matches the description (staggered contacts).

[image: flex side of connector]

Thanks for taking a look, folks!